# How can i configure a load balanced ntp servers

Tags: ntp

i want to use `ntp.nict.jp` server for ntp in my linux machine .
When i am configuring this server am getting the following ntp status :

```
[root@machine~]# ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 ntp-a2.nict.go. .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

What i could see is that the domain `ntp.nict.jp`  is load balanced to different domains

```
ntp-b3.nict.go.jp(133.243.238.164)
ntp-a3.nict.go.jp(133.243.238.244)
ntp-b2.nict.go.jp(133.243.238.163)
ntp-a2.nict.go.jp(133.243.238.243)
```

and if i am configuring any of the domains in the above list , the ntp works fine .

i wish to configure the entire servers under `ntp.nict.jp` for ntp.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "pool" command in the ntp.conf file as follows.

> pool ntp.nict.jp iburst